# Forçar ordem de execução de eventos do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supondo uma página que tenha vários eventos sendo associados via jQuery. Por exemplo, em determinado trecho, tenho:

```
$().ready(function() {
    foo();
});
```

E mais a frente tenho:

```
$().ready(function() {
    bar();
});
```

E várias linhas mais abaixo...

```
$().ready(function() {
    VoceJahEntendeuAIdeia();
});
```

Agora supondo que eu deseje forçar a ordem de execução dos eventos. Existe alguma forma de se fazer `bar();` rodar antes de `foo();`, que não envolva necessariamente mudar os dois de posição ou modificar o código do jQuery?

O motivo é que estou lidando com código injetado na aplicação através dos eventos `load` e `ready` do jQuery, por componentes de um framework que estou utilizando. Tal framework necessariamente injeta seu prório código por último na carga da página, mas eu realmente preciso que meu código rode por último. E eu acho o uso de `setTimeout`/`setInterval` deselegante.

Comment: Uma maneira seria uma função de `callback` a ser chamada após o código da _framework_, mas sem uma ideia mais concreta de como as coisas estão a acontecer, é difícil facultar uma solução adequada ao cenário em questão. Dá para adicionar um pouco mais de informação sobre a maneira como esse código da _framework_ está a ser injectado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você não pode modificar o código de nenhuma maneira, minha única sugestão é fazer um ["*monkey patch*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) na função `jQuery.fn.ready`, para especificar uma ordem de execução. Coloque esse código **antes** de todos os demais (porém **depois** de inserir o script com o próprio jQuery, é claro):

```
var ordem = [0,2,3,1]; // Especifica a ordem desejada
var iniciadores = []; // Acumula os iniciadores
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Executa os iniciadores na ordem
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < ordem.length ; i++ ) {
        var x = iniciadores[ordem[i]];
        x[0].apply(x[1], x[2]);
    }
    // Remove o "monkey patch"
    $.fn.ready = oldReady;
});

var oldReady = $.fn.ready; // Guarda o ready original
// Monkey patch
$.fn.ready = function(fn) {
    if ( this[0] == document ) // Se for no document...
        iniciadores.push([fn, this, arguments]); // não execute, acumule
    else
        return oldReady.apply(this, arguments); // Senão execute
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbN33/1/).

Comment: Nota: se você acha `setTimeout` deselegante, esse você vai achar mais ainda... :P Mas é uma alternativa.

Comment: Não acho mais deselegante - sendo bem documentado, vai fazer mais sentido para o próximo desenvolvedor do que um `setTimeout` gratuito. Obrigado :) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não há uma forma de fazer isso, porém caso ajude, você pode delegar um evento de load para executar o seu script. Assim ele só será executado quando todos os componentes da página, incluindo o que foi inserido por ultimo, forem carregados.

Comment: Apenas como observação, realmente o método `.load()` da jQuery foi depreciado, porém você ainda pode utilizar do método `.on()` para delegar o evento.

Comment: Caso você não conheça a forma de uso, pode ver alguns exemplos neste artigo meu: http://jquerybrasil.org/delegando-e-removendo-eventos-com-on-e-off/

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples, mas não muito elegante na forma como está:

```
$('#teste').on('click',     function(e){ console.log( 1, e.type ); }); // 3
$('#teste').on('mousedown', function(e){ console.log( 2, e.type ); }); // 1
$('#teste').on('mouseup',   function(e){ console.log( 3, e.type ); }); // 2
$('#teste').on('click',     function(e){ console.log( 4, e.type ); }); // 4

// Alterando a ordem

// Salva eventos originais de click
var eventosOriginais = jQuery.extend( true, {}, $._data($("#teste")[0], "events").click );
// Apaga os eventos
$('#teste').off('click')
// readiciona os eventos na ordem desejada
$('#teste').on('click', function(e){ 
    eventosOriginais[1].handler(e);
    eventosOriginais[0].handler(e);
})
```

com algum trabalho, você automatiza o re-bind dos eventos, para o modo como vc deseja

[exemplo funcional no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/letanure/yuwCz/)

Outra opção, só para resolver o seu problema é procurar algum outro evento que normalmente é disparado antes, como no exemplo, **mousedown** e **mouseup** acontecem antes do **click**

Comment: Fiz um teste, e parece que isso não vai funcionar para o document.ready (que é o caso da pergunta). `$._data(x, "events")` retorna `undefined` para `document`, `document.body` e `window`.

Comment: fiz testes com _document_ e não funcionou mesmo. Essa solução funciona apenas em objetos do ***DOM***, procurar alguma opção e complemento